# When should I use poppler_page_render vs poppler_page_render_for_printing?

Tags: cairo, poppler

There are two functions to render a PopplerPage on a cairo surface: `poppler_page_render` and `poppler_page_render_for_printing`. The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/poppler/unstable/PopplerPage.html#poppler-page-render-for-printing) states that the latter should be used "to render a page that will be printed".

My question is: which one of these should I use if my cairo surface will be later saved as a (pdf) file? Does saving as a file constitute a poppler "printing"? I would appreciate a reference to documentation.
Does it matter that the PopplerPage was created from a pdf file by `poppler_document_get_page`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at poppler's source code, the difference is, for example, that annotations are displayed, but not printed:

http://sources.debian.net/src/poppler/0.44.0-3/glib/poppler-page.cc/?hl=362#L362
http://sources.debian.net/src/poppler/0.44.0-3/glib/poppler-page.cc/?hl=309#L309